# Spring Boot: How do you specify an environment variable that has dashes in the application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an `application.properties` file that looks like this:

```
mcl.sso.frontend-url=http://blah.com:9001
mcl.sso.mocking-agent=false
```

I am trying to override these two variables from the command line.  This should be possible by setting environment variables.  Here's how I'm running the command:

```
MCL_SSO_FRONTEND_URL='foobar' MCL_SSO_MOCKING_AGENT='true' ./gradlew run
```

However, when I print out the values of these variables, `mcl.sso.mocking-agent` equals "true" (as expected), but `mcl.sso.frontend-url` still equals "http://blah.com:9001" (unexpected).  Why doesn't `mcl.sso.frontend-url` change the value of the property?  I can only assume this has something to do with the way Spring converts environment variables into property keys, but I can't find any specific documentation on this.

Comment: You're looking for "relaxed property binding", and the way that it's actually implemented is... subelegant. I don't remember off the top of my head where the generator for it is, but that might be a start.

Comment: Refer: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding this should work

Comment: @AnandShah thanks, that's a useful reference.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From [spring-boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables):

### Binding from Environment Variables

Most operating systems impose strict rules around the names that can be used for environment variables. For example, Linux shell variables can contain only letters (`a` to `z` or `A` to `Z`), numbers (`0` to `9`) or the underscore character (`_`). By convention, Unix shell variables will also have their names in UPPERCASE.

Spring Boot’s relaxed binding rules are, as much as possible, designed to be compatible with these naming restrictions.

To convert a property name in the canonical-form to an environment variable name you can follow these rules:

- Replace dots (`.`) with underscores (`_`).
- Remove any dashes (`-`).
- Convert to uppercase.

For example, the configuration property `spring.main.log-startup-info` would be an environment variable named `SPRING_MAIN_LOGSTARTUPINFO`.

Environment variables can also be used when binding to object lists. To bind to a `List`, the element number should be surrounded with underscores in the variable name.

For example, the configuration property `my.service[0].other` would use an environment variable named `MY_SERVICE_0_OTHER`.

Answer (score 9):

This has been fixed as of Spring Boot `1.2.5`. Previously, you'd have to use `MCL_SSO_FRONTEND-URL` (notice the dash that can't be translated to an underscore).

You can play with bindings using [this sample project](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/spring-boot-configuration-binding).

Comment: On Linux dashes are not allowed in environment variable keys. The solution is to use `MCL_SSO_FRONTENDURL`. I.e. no delimiter in the property name itself. Documented here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0

Comment: Doron, that's exactly what I wrote, don't I? Previously the dash should be added, no longer necessary.

Comment: Stephane: Eveidently that's what you meant. It wasn't clear to me that there should be **no** delimeter in the property name, even if it consists of multiple words. After reading your answer I had to play with this a bit before I got it right. Just wanted to make it clear.

Comment: Dropping the hyphen from the env variable doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: @DoronGold the answer mentions Spring Boot 1.2.5 but your comment references functionality available in Spring Boot 2.x. This might confuse people into thinking that it's available in older versions as well, especially considering that the linked page doesn't mention in which version of SB was it introduced.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I think it's good to include both old and new format in your answer so that people finding your answer by googling find the format quickly

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but Spring Boot 1.2.x is EOL for years, I hope you're not using that version :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just get rid of the dash:

```
mcl.sso.mocking-agent > MCL_SSO_MOCKINGAGENT
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure about the rules, you can use the CLI tools which does the translation automatically

https://github.com/helpermethod/p2e