# ConfigurationProperties for String properties with multiple dots

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to fix a bug in our company's homemade framework. Basically, we should be able to inject EclipseLink properties into the `EntityManager` through the following class which is part of our framework:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "our.framework.eclipselink")
public class CustomEclipseLinkProperties {

    private Map<String, Object> properties;

    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public String getBatchSize() {
        return (String) properties.get(PersistenceUnitProperties.BATCH_WRITING_SIZE);
    }

}
```

Our service built on top of that framework has the following properties file (`application.properties`):

```
our.framework.eclipselink.properties.eclipselink.logging.level=FINEST
our.framework.eclipselink.properties.eclipselink.logging.level.cache=FINEST
our.framework.eclipselink.properties.eclipselink.logging.level.sql=FINEST
our.framework.eclipselink.properties.eclipselink.logging.parameters=true

our.framework.eclipselink.properties.eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size=1000
our.framework.eclipselink.properties.eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters=true
our.framework.eclipselink.properties.eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing=JDBC

our.framework.eclipselink.properties.eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names=false
our.framework.eclipselink.properties.eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-columns=false
```

When I put a breakpoint after the `CustomEclipseLinkProperties` has been initialized, I can see that `getBatchSize()` returns `null`. If I look into `getProperties()`, I do see the values were detected, but they were inserted as a `LinkedHashMap`.

[image: Debug mode]

The expected behavior would be that we would obtain a `Map` that would use the entire suffix as the String key, rather than getting this `LinkedHashMap` that has essentially called `String#split()` on the properties list. This would mean that the call to `getBatchSize()` would return `1000`.

I've seen a few answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31051377/9768291) but they don't seem generic enough to my liking. **Is there not a way to simply get the entire suffix as the key when injected by `@ConfigurationProperties`?** Else, it seems like it would require intervention whenever we would want to support a different type of property.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620916/spring-boot-how-do-you-specify-an-environment-variable-that-has-dashes-in-the-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out "suffix as key" is the default behavior if I swap from `Map<String, Object>` to `Map<String, String>`.

The `Object` value isn't actually useful in our case, so that solves this problem.