# How can I get Spring Boot REST API to communicate with Elasticsearch in a Docker environment?

Tags: spring, docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying to set up communication between a Spring application and Elasticsearch in a Docker environment, but when I run the program, I get the following warning:

**.d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : Cannot create index: Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused**

When entering a command in the browser: *http://localhost:9200/article/_search?pretty=true*, I get the information that the index does not exist

I tried to change different configurations in docker-compose and spring application, but I couldn't fix the error

However, when I run the program manually (*without Docker containerization*), then the program works correctly

My **docker-compose.yml** config is simplified as much as possible:

```
version: '3'

services:

  demo:
    container_name: demo
    image: demo-elastic
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - es
    networks:
      - demo-network

  es:
    image: elasticsearch:7.6.2
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - demo-network

networks:
  demo-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Standard **Dockerfile**

```
# For Java 11
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} demo.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/demo.jar"]
```

**Config.java** file for Elasticsearch configuration in java application

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.demo.repository")
public class Config extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.url}")
    public String elasticsearchUrl;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration config = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo(elasticsearchUrl)
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(config).rest();
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
elasticsearch.url=localhost:9200
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9200
```

Main dependencies in **pom.xml** file. My Spring Boot version is 2.7.5

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a program accesses localhost within a container, it points to its own container. To fix this, change the Spring configuration to use "es:9200" as the Elasticsearch access point. In this case, "es" is used as the hostname of the Elasticsearch server.

Update:

In your application.properties file, you can set your configurations for manual runs. However, when running in a container, you can override these settings using environment variables. Here's an example:

In application.properties:

```
elasticsearch.url=localhost:9200
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9200
```

Then in your Dockerfile or docker-compose file, you can override these settings:

```
demo:
  container_name: demo
  image: demo-elastic
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  environment:
    - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=es:9200
    - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTERNODES=es:9200
  depends_on:
    - es
  networks:
    - demo-network
```

This way, the properties set in your Spring application will be overridden by the environment variables when the application is run in a container.

For rules of binding configuration from environment variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71680394/775640

Comment: After I changed `elasticsearch.url=es:9200` my docker container began to work correctly. However, now when I run the application manually (without docker), the index cannot be created.

How can I configure docker-compose so that the changed setting affects only the launch of the docker container, without changing the configuration in application.properties?

Comment: You can use environment variable in container to override application.properties configuration. see my answer update.